# George Polya's theorem on the number of shortest routes on Pascal's Triangle

Tags: combinatorics, proof-writing, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs

How does one prove George Polya's theorem in Pascal's Triangle that the number of shortest routes from the point representing $_0C_0$ to the point representing  $_nC_r$ is $_nC_r$?

Here, $_nC_r = \frac{n!}{(n-r)!r!}$.

Comment: Hint: That number satisfies the same recursion relation as ${}_nC_r$.

Comment: I apologize for my ignorance but can you elaborate more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this by induction!

**Base case.** Let $n=1$. To get from ${0\choose0}$ to ${1\choose0}$ and from ${0\choose0}$ to ${1\choose 1}$ there is only one path in each case, since ${1\choose0}$ and ${1\choose1}$ are both adjacent to ${0\choose0}.$

**Inductive hypothesis.** Now, assume that the number of paths from ${0\choose0}$ to ${k\choose r}$ is ${k\choose r}$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}^+$.

Now, how many ways are there to get to ${k+1\choose r}$? First, we note that in order to get to ${k+1\choose r}$, we *must* come from either ${k\choose r}$ or ${k\choose r-1}$, since they are directly to the upper-right and upper-left, respectively. Therefore, there are ${k\choose r} + {k\choose r-1} = {k+1\choose r}$ ways to get to ${k+1\choose r}$.

Note that in the above argument, $r\ne k+1$. To get this case, we see that the only choice is to run along the right edge, giving us a single path.

To really flesh out this proof, you should prove two things I glossed over:

> - Any path to ${n\choose k}$ must come from ${n-1\choose k}$ of ${n-1\choose k-1}$.
> - ${n\choose k} = {n-1\choose k}+{n-1\choose k-1}$.

Comment: Wow. Brilliant. I need this theorem for my undergraduate research paper. My professor told us this theorem last semester but he did not teach us the proof. I've already spent around three hours trying to prove this. You saved me a lot of time. Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem! Good luck with your paper!